# Two 5/8 drywall panel on resilient channel RC-1 on ceiling

Tags: sound-proofing

Can you mount two layers of 5/8 drywall on RC-1 from the ceiling?

Comment: This should actually be answered by the manufacturer.

Comment: Have you checked the Gypsum Association's database of assemblies?